# CSS - Having trouble centering div under header using transform

Tags: html, css

I have been having some trouble figuring this out so I have decided to include both my html and css in full this time.

I want my calendar section to be centered on the page below my header section which is to be fixed at the top of the page. I want my code to be dynamic so I am using translate to center my calendar.

When I view my code using IE or Edge the calendar is set in front of my header (centered horizontally but not vertically).

Could this have to do with my using positioning along with transforms?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet2.css"/> 
    <title></title>
<!--------------------------header--------------------------->
    <div id="headerDiv">
        <div id="titleDiv">
            <p id= "titleText"> Title </p>
        </div>
        <ul id="navUL">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Browse</li>
            <li>Stats</li>
            <li>Calculator</li>
            <li>Blaster</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</head>
<!--------------------------calendar------------------------->
<body>
    <div class="calendar">

            <div>
                <p class="month">December</p>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="cell">Sunday</th>
                        <th class="cell">Monday</th>
                        <th class="cell">Tuesday</th>
                        <th class="cell">Wednesday</th>
                        <th class="cell">Thursday</th>
                        <th class="cell">Friday</th>  
                        <th class="cell">Saturday</th>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">29</td>
                        <td class="cell">30</td>
                        <td class="cell">1</td>
                        <td class="cell">2</td>
                        <td class="cell">3</td>
                        <td class="cell">4</td>
                        <td class="cell">5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">6</td>
                        <td class="cell">7</td>
                        <td class="cell">8</td>
                        <td class="cell">9</td>
                        <td class="cell">10</td>
                        <td class="cell">11</td>
                        <td class="cell">12</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">13</td>
                        <td class="cell">14</td>
                        <td class="cell">15</td>
                        <td class="cell">16</td>
                        <td class="cell">17</td>
                        <td class="cell">18</td>
                        <td class="cell">19</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">20</td>
                        <td class="cell">21</td>
                        <td class="cell">22</td>
                        <td class="cell">23</td>
                        <td class="cell">24</td>
                        <td class="cell">25</td>
                        <td class="cell">26</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell">27</td>
                        <td class="cell">28</td>
                        <td class="cell">29</td>
                        <td class="cell">30</td>
                        <td class="cell">31</td>
                        <td class="cell">1</td>
                        <td class="cell">2</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*-------------------header----------------------*/

body{
margin:0px;
}
#headerDiv{
position: fixed;
height:12%;

width:100%;
background-image:url("Gradient.png");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
text-align: center;
}


#titleDiv{

width: auto;
margin: auto 0;
}

#titleText{

color:#ff6600;

font-size:130%;

text-allign:center;
font-family:verdana,san serif;

}

#navUL{
list-style-type:none;
margin: auto 0;
padding:0;
border-top:1 solid;
border-right:1 solid;
border-left:1 solid;
width:100%;
}
#navUL li{
padding: .2em 1em;
color: #fff;
background-color: #036;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;

}

/*------------------calendar--------------------*/


.calendar{

text-align:center;
float:left;

background-color:#ffeeff;

height:80%;

width:70%;
position:relative;
top:80%;
left:50%;
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}


.month{
padding-bottom:-20%;
font-size:260%;
text-align:center;
}
table,th,td{
border: 1px solid black;
text-align:center;
}
table{
text-align:center;
margin: 0 auto;
border-collapse: collapse;
width:100%
}
```

Comment: Note that your `#headerDiv` block should be part of the `body`, not the `head`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header should be in the body. If you want the calendar centered try either the following:

1. Include text-align:center in the body or..
2. Margin:auto in .calender or..
3. TranslateX(-50%) and margin-left: -35% or use pixels for width like 300px and then use margin-left: -150px which centers it.

If it doesnt work try absolute positioning. I hope this helps :).

Comment: Yup looks like the header being in the body was the problem. Thanks!